# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException on UAT server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am facing org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException . Stacktrace is this -

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.abc.magic.core.music.domain.Song.songAdministratorsNoAgreement, could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
com.abc.common.MusicPageFlowFilter.doFilter(MusicPageFlowFilter.java:76)
com.abc.common.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:81)
com.abc.common.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:68)
```

Now the main issue is, same build is deployed on dev and on my local machine. My Local, Dev and UAT, all three are pointing to same DB. But on local and on Dev same build is working fine, but when I am deploying my war to UAT, I am getting this exception.

I have already checked to find out session.close present if any. There are none. To avoid some lazy fetching occuring outside of @Transactional scope, I have put @Transactional on both controller and service layer classes.

But still my war is working perfectly fine on Dev and Local, where as on UAT I am getting this exception. How I can debug this? What can be the possible reasons for this?

### Thanks

Akshay

Comment: Oh most likely there is still a bug in the code and the actual problem is that you -don't- get it on the two other environments. But I understand if you really want to blame the tools at this point, so if you want to follow that path for now then you'll just have to investigate if there is something different in the UAT server itself. What application server is this running on? Are the datasource configurations correct? Same JDBC driver? Same version of Hibernate? etc. etc.

Comment: I dont care for blaming any tool or any thing, I just want to fix this issue on ASAP. But It is getting difficult since I am not able to replicate same on environment where I have all the required rights. and yes, I have checked datasource configuration, driver, hibernate, possibility of having session.close(), calling DB operation out side method annotated with @Transactional annotation, value of current session context class in the hibernate property.. but still no luck :(

Comment: I feel your pain, but reproducing the problem locally stays the #1 priority if you ever want to solve anything. Are you sure this is the only exception in the log? Generally when I get a "no proxy" exception it is because there was an earlier failure that triggered the transaction to be rolled back.

Comment: Secondary suggestion: try remote debugging. It should be possible to connect a local IDE to the runtime running on the UAT server if you start it up with proper debug flags, and be able to debug the remote application from your local IDE. That is not trivial to setup, but it might in the end save the day. this is really old but it should give a good starting point: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/ .